# read_exif_data not showing the correct data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using `read_exif_data` function to get details about uploaded image but in some cases data does not showing correctly.
I am sharing the output for a image in which resolution is showing less then 1

```
Array
(
[FileName] => 1444195025.jpg
[FileDateTime] => 1444195025
[FileSize] => 1777209
[FileType] => 2
[MimeType] => image/jpeg
[SectionsFound] => ANY_TAG, IFD0, THUMBNAIL, EXIF
[COMPUTED] => Array
    (
        [html] => width="1893" height="1494"
        [Height] => 1494
        [Width] => 1893
        [IsColor] => 1
        [ByteOrderMotorola] => 0
        [Copyright] =>

    )

[ImageWidth] => 1893
[ImageLength] => 1494
[BitsPerSample] => 8
[Compression] => 1
[PhotometricInterpretation] => 1
[ImageDescription] =>
[Orientation] => 1
[SamplesPerPixel] => 1
**[XResolution] => 1/316
[YResolution] => 372/283465**
[ResolutionUnit] => 3
[Software] => '
[DateTime] => 5.1 Windows
[Artist] => 03 23:26:03
[Copyright] =>
[Exif_IFD_Pointer] => 316
[THUMBNAIL] => Array
    (
        [Compression] => 6
        [XResolution] => 72/1
        [YResolution] => 72/1
        [ResolutionUnit] => 2
        [JPEGInterchangeFormat] => 466
        [JPEGInterchangeFormatLength] => 8382
    )

[ExifVersion] => 0221
[ColorSpace] => 1
[ExifImageWidth] => 1893
[ExifImageLength] => 1494
 )
```

I am confused about how a image have `resolution less then 1` whereas image size about `1.8 MB`. I am using codeigniter framework.

Comment: Can you show us your code where you are using this function?